# Null Pointer Exception when Audio Record Stopping

Tags: android, audio, nullpointerexception

I need to record audio from an Android device. Start of recording is working fine, but i cannot stop audio recording. I am getting a null pointer exception error. I am accessing `start()` and `stop()` method from other classes. When I use the `stop` method the record is null.

Here is my audio class

```
private String getFilename(){
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        if(!file.exists()){
                file.mkdirs();
        }

        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/Questionnair_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + file_exts[currentFormat]);
}
         public String startRecording(){

                recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);
                recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);


                recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
                recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
                recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener); 



        try {
                recorder.prepare();
                recorder.start();
                //dbstore(getFilename());






        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }



}
    private MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener = new        MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
           @Override
            public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                AppLog.logString("Error: " + what + ", " + extra);
        }
};


public static Context getAppContext()
{
return Audio.context;
}
private MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                AppLog.logString("Warning: " + what + ", " + extra);
        }
};




        public void stopRecording(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("stoping");


              try {

                  if (null != recorder) {
                        System.out.println("recrder is null");

                  recorder.stop();
                  recorder.release();
                  recorder  = null;

                  }

               } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    //  it is called before start()


                    e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    // no valid audio/video data has been received
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }
        }
```

Here is the code how i am accessing methods

```
new Audio().startRecording();
new Audio().stopRecording();
```

How to fix this issue for stop audio recording

Comment: Can you please show more of your code

Comment: there is complete Audio class and method calling code.what you want more?

Comment: the trouble seek  between the stopRecording method, what you are calling and what you have implemented [with view parameter] please check. By the way , dont call stopRecording with a new instance of your audio class, use the same instance with which you are calling the start method

Comment: okay leave it that view parameter.can u provide  code for stoprecording in same instance?plz?

Comment: Just save the first instance that you create when calling `startRecording`, and use it again when calling `stopRecording`.

Comment: give me sample code plz. I am new to android

Comment: try this, http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/06/voice-recording-in-android.html

Comment: I used that tutorial only.can u give code for that same instance concepts?

Comment: @vibinreji which is line no. 95 ?

Comment: @AngadTiwari Sorry that error log is updated code.By the way issue is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like:

```
private Audio mAudio;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAudio = new Audio();
    mAudio.startRecording();               

}

public void stopRecording(){

    if(mAudio != null){

        mAudio.stopRecording();

    }

}
```